# JBPM Multi-Instance loop Characteristics with "Sequential instead of Parallel Execution" not working

Tags: java, workflow, jbpm, bpmn, business-process-management

We have requirement to use generate tasks depends on input variables but Task should be executed in Sequence instead of parallel.

For above requirement

- I am using Multi-Instance Sub-process to generate the tasks based on input parameter.
- To execute in sequence In process definition I can see there is option in multi-instance sub-process loop characteristics "**Sequential instead of Parallel Execution**".

> I turned it on so that it executes in sequence but on start of sub
>   process it still executing in parallel (default behavior)

***PLEASE HELP***

.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to reply so late but someone new can use this.

The true or false value on isSequential makes all the difference

```
<userTask id="miTasks" name="My Task" activiti:assignee="${assignee}">
  <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false"
     activiti:collection="assigneeList" activiti:elementVariable="assignee" >
    <completionCondition>${nrOfCompletedInstances/nrOfInstances >= 0.6 }</completionCondition>
  </multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
</userTask>
```

https://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#bpmnMultiInstance

Comment: Thanks! Looks like your answer in context of Alfresco Activity? I was looking in JBPM.